# I/O errno 121 error when running a python script

Tags: python, io, raspberry-pi3

I have gotten a company's fan hat and with it came some code. However on running the code (via thonny through the files) I keep getting the error,

```
file "/home/pi/fam_tempf.pi", line 23, in <module>
bus.write_byte_data(addr, fan_reg, 0x01)
osError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error
```

pls help... the code is,

```
import time
import os
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

time.sleep(2)

addr = 0x0d
fan_reg = 0x08
state = 0
temp = 0
level_temp = 0

while True:
    cmd = os.popen('vcgencmd measure_temp').readline()
    CPU_TEMP = cmd.replace("temp=","").replace("'C\n","")
    print(CPU_TEMP)
    temp = float(CPU_TEMP)
    
    if temp <= 35:
        bus.write_byte_data(addr, fan_reg, 0x02)
    elif temp >= 36:
        bus.write_byte_data(addr, fan_reg, 0x01)

    time.sleep(1)
```

and the error is listed above^^^^^^^^^